# CakePHP - View file doesn't recognize passed variables from the Controller

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller

So I have this controller called `TestsController` with the following code:

```
class TestsController extends AppController
{
    public function index($arg1,$arg2){
        $this->set('argument1',$arg1);
        $this->set('argument2',$arg2);
    }
}
```

When I try to call these variables in my 'index.ctp' file located in Template/Tests/index.ctp it doesn't recognize them and underlines them.

This is the code for `index.ctp`:

```
Argument-1: <?php $argument1?> <br />
Argument-2: <?php $argument2?> <br />
```

My route should be fine:

```
$routes->connect('tests/:arg1/:arg2', 
    ['controller' => 'Tests', 'action' => 'index'], 
    ['pass' => ['arg1', 'arg2']]);
```

When I go to the URL for my Tests controller with parameters, the values for those parameters don't show up.
I've looked everywhere for an answer, would love some help.

Comment: maybe because you did not echo them? ```<?= $argument1 ?>``` instead of ```<?php $argument1 ?>```

Answer (score 0):

The view should be:

```
Argument-1: <?php echo $argument1?> <br />
Argument-2: <?php echo $argument2?> <br />
```

Or:

```
Argument-1: <?= $argument1?> <br />
Argument-2: <?= $argument2?> <br />
```